Background on notation for generative models
In many papers on generative modeling and Bayesian inference in statistics, I come across the following kind of notation, in particular for hierarchical models.
For variables $x_1, \dots, x_n$, it looks something like this:
$$
x_1 \sim D_1 \quad \text{(for some distribution $D_1$)} \\
x_2 \mid x_1 \sim D_2(x_1) \quad \text{(for some distribution $D_2$ with one parameter)} \\
x_3 \mid x_1, x_2 \sim D_3(x_1, x_2) \quad \text{(for some distribution $D_3$ with two parameters)} \\
x_4 \mid x_2, x_3 = f(x_2, x_3) \quad \text{(for some binary function $f$)} \\
\vdots
$$
The notation is quite intuitive and seems to be related to Bayesian networks: each line describes a variable's conditional distribution given its parents in the directed acyclic graph.
Does this notation have a name? When and by whom was it introduced? Is it standard? Is there a reference with a precise description?

The notation you described is essentially (hierarchical) standard conditional distributions and used in any context of Bayesian hierarchical models including its application in some Bayesian networks when a hierarchical model is appropriate. Though it may not be a difficult model conceptually but it's been widely disseminated and advocated through the works of Judea Pearl and Andrew Gelman from early 80s. In "Bayesian Data Analysis, Third Edition, 2013." by Gelman et al, they described a famous eight schools problem solved by a Bayesian hierarchical model which was first published in 1981 by Rubin in a paper called " Estimation in parallel randomized experiments. Journal of Educational Statistics".
The eight schools problem considers the effectiveness of SAT coaching programs conducted in parallel at eight schools which has become a classic problem to illustrate the usefulness of the full Bayesian hierarchical modeling for sharing information between exchangeable groups. There may be earlier published similar models, but this one is classic.
